# Many-to-many relationship INSERT

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to create a many to many relationship between 2 tables. I've got 3 tables for that. It follows TOXY model.

```
table a: a.id (primary key)
table ab: ab.a_id (foreign key) ab.b_id (foreign key)
table b: b.id (primary key)
```

How should I insert the data so it will be all linked up?

Like this? `"INSERT INTO a ('name') VALUES ('my name')";`

then like this? `"INSERT INTO b ('name') VALUES ('my name')";`

but then I have to have the a.id and b.id to put it in table ab. How should I retrieve them?

i know i could do a SELECT a.id FROM a WHERE name = 'my name'. but isnt there an easier way for this that automatically returns an id when u INSERT the row?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All you need to do is store those IDs in variables to use in a query to insert into the `ab` table. `LAST_INSERT_ID()` returns the ID of the inserted rows. So, in PHP for instance:

```
// Run command to insert into A, then:
$a = mysql_query('SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();');

// Run command to insert into B, then:
$b = mysql_query('SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();');

// Then $a and $b hold the IDs that you can use to insert into AB.
mysql_query("INSERT INTO ab (a_id, b_id) VALUES ($a, $b);");
```

Comment: +! for the detail I did not provide

Comment: wait! it doesnt work! because it says when i try to echo $a:

Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in /Volumes/Private/johnnyluu/Sites/sandbox/test/index.php on line 35

Comment: im using mysqli version. maybe that is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain the value stored into the auto_increment primary key column by calling the [mysql_insert_id() function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html):

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()
```

Comment: what is the difference between last_insert_id and mysql_insert_id?

Comment: The `mysql_insert_id` is the C API call, with is really calling `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()`.  The details are in the link I provided to the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the TOXY model is, but you would use a simple join:

`SELECT * FROM a INNER JOIN ab on a.id=ab.a_id WHERE ab.b_id = {b.id};`

and for your instance, {b.id} would be last_insert_id();